# Batch-wise training with ImageDataGenerator

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, generator

I have a training dataset which is prepared as follows:

```
FileName              
s01_l01/1_1.png     

Labels_onehot
[[0.0, 0.0, 0.0,..., 1.0],..., [0.0, 0.0, 1.0,..., 0.0]]
```

`FileName` directly leads to the input images. I would like to preprocess the images (resize them to (224, 224) and rescale them (1./255). `Labels_onehot` are the one hot encoded labels. These do not have to be further preprocessed.

In the end, the preprocessed images are my `X_train` data.

```
X_train.shape
(n, 224, 224, 3)
```

The labels are the `y_train` data.

```
y_train.shape
(n, 8, 36)
```

Until now, I am preprocessing the images manually and then loading the preprocessed images (one dataset) and the labels (other dataset). This is not a very efficient way and fills out my RAM completely.

But in the end I am able to fit my model relatively easy, e.g. with this code:

```
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=50, batch_size=32)
```

Now, I am wondering, how to achieve the same with the `ImageDataGenerator`. Is there a method to do all the steps I did before manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ImageDataGenerator has a number of methods

1. flow: Takes feature data & label arrays, and returns an iterator that produces generates augmented data batches.
2. flow_from_directory: Takes a path to a directory and generates batches of augmented data.

First, we will create an instance of ImageDataGenerator.

```
aug = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator( rotation_range=20,
width_shift_range=0.1, shear_range=0.2, zoom_range=0.4, horizontal_flip=True)
```

- **rotation_range**: degrees (0 to 180).
- **width_shift_range** and **height_shift_range** are used for horizontal and
  vertical shifts,respectively.
- **zoom_range**: the amount of zoom. If scalar z, the zoom will be
  randomly picked in the range [1-z, 1+z].
- **horizontal_flip**: whether to randomly flip images horizontally.
- **vertical_flip**: whether to randomly flip images vertically.
- **rescale**: rescaling factor. This multiplies the image by the rescaling factor. This can be a useful way of normalising the data by specifying a rescaling factor of 1.0/255.

flow function returns a generator, which is a Python iterator object that is used to construct our augmented images

```
flow_train_generator = aug.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size=32)
```

flow_from_directory method returns an Iterator that yields tuples of (x, y) where x is a NumPy array containing a batch of images and y is a NumPy array of corresponding labels.

```
flow_dict_train_generator = aug.flow_from_directory(
        'data/train',
        target_size=(150, 150),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='binary')
```

Please be aware that the flow from the directory can slow down your model training process as you read directly from the disk each time you generate a new batch before making the modifications to the data increase and then pass the batch to the network.

For more details you can refer below link:
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Are these methods applicable for my problem? Honestly, I am not sure and that is because of the shape of `y_train`... The flow-method looks promising but how can I resize the pictures with it? I don't see a way to do this... Can we maybe proceed in chat?

Comment: yeah sure. email me on ronny2497@gmail.com